# Paypal and session variables

Tags: paypal

Hi This is all out of my league so I could do with some help with this.

I have a simple website that uses paypal as the means of payment, but all payment will be different. With the below code if I have a fixed number it works fine but as mentioned it will be a different amount each time. I am using classic asp and the session to help with the variable but it's not working.

In my ASP page I have a simple test code:

```
  <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>      
  Session("pay") = "1.00"
  <div id="paypal-button-container" style="float: right;" style="width: 50%"></div>
```

and in the JS file

```
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '<%=Session("pay")%>', currency: 'GBP' }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Comment: Anybody please!!!